# Type a pre defined text when a shortcut key is pressed in Windows 7

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, automation

I work on mainframes and don't have much knowledge about windows other than playing warcraft :-) hence pardon me if I ask something nooby/silly.

I have a requirement to enter a particular long-text in the current position of a cursor whenever a shortcut key is pressed.

I am thinking of creating a bat file and assigning a windows keyboard shortcut to the bat file and whenever I have requirement to enter the long text, I press the windows shortcut key
and the long text gets typed in the current position of the cursor.

The current position of the cursor can be in any application, like Excel, Word or notepad or Windows dialog prompts.

Could you please let me know if this is possible and point me where I could get some information about this "technique".

Thanks & Regards,
Vasanth.S

Comment: if an external programm is an option: AutoIT was suggested several times here. (I don't know it, but I know AutoHotKey - I think, they work on the same principes)

Answer (score 0):

To make a single key combo do what you are asking, you may need another program.  You can make a link to a batch file, hook up a shortcut and then use the clip command to copy text from a file onto the clipboard.  That would require the shortcut and then a Ctrl+V to paste.  The batch file would look like this:

```
clip < c:\SomeDir\sometext.txt
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I got the requirement working with "WshShell.SendKeys" and calling the VB script from bat file. However, your tip on clip to copy stuff to clipboard is slick, I will use it for some other requirement. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to look at using a clipboard manager - which saves a history of clipboard entries, can search for an entry, and paste it at the cursor.

`Ditto` and `CLCL` are both useful and free - which one you use depends on your windows version.

They are hotkey driven for ease of use, but mouse can be used.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, but I forgot to mention that this is a work PC and I cannot install 3rd party softwares :S  I tried working with "WshShell.SendKeys" and got it to work on most applications except "internet explorer". Thanks again